# awk ternay operator, count fs with ,

Tags: awk

How to make this command line:

```
awk -F "," '{NF>0?$NF:$0}'
```

to print the last field of a line if `NF>0`, otherwise print the whole line?

**Working data**

```
bogota
dept math, bogota
```

Comment: Not a bash question at all, unless you would accept an answer that didn't use `awk`. Awk is not part of bash; it's a separate language, usable from any shell or with no shell at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  awk -F, '{ print ( NF ? $NF : $0 ) }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need ternary operator for this, but use :

```
awk -F, '{print $NF}' file
```

This will print the last field, i.e, if there are more than 1 field, it will print the last field, if line has only one field, it will print the same.